# is it possible to add to a list while preserving the order of the html being read using beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, html, pandas, beautifulsoup, list-manipulation

I have the following code being read using beautifulsoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = '''
<h1 class="ch">Ch 4:Chapter Title</h1>
<h2 class="subchapter">subch. 1:Subchapter Title 1</h2>

<div>
    <div>
        <div class="left">sec 1.</div>
        <div class="right">belongs to left sec 1</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="left">sec 2.</div>
        <div class="right">belongs to left sec 2</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="left">sec 3.</div>
        <div class="right">belongs to left sec 3</div>
    </div>
</div>

<h2 class="subchapter">subch. 2:Subchapter Title 2</h2>

<div>
    <div>
        <div class="left">sec 4.</div>
        <div class="right">belongs to left sec 4</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="left">sec 5.</div>
        <div class="right">belongs to left sec 5</div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <div class="left">sec 6.</div>
        <div class="right">belongs to left sec 6</div>
    </div>
</div>
'''

lst = []
s = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

chs = s.find_all('h1', attrs={'class':'ch'})
subchs = s.find_all('h2', attrs={'class': 'subchapter'})
secns = s.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'left'})
sectxts = s.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'right'})

if chs:
   for ch in chs:
      chapter = ch.text
      ch_citation = re.search(r".*:", chapter).group()
      ch_title = re.sub(r".*:","",chapter)

if subchs:
   for subch in subchs:
      subchapter = subch.text
      subch_citation = re.search(r".*:", subchapter).group()
      subch_title = re.sub(r".*:","",subchapter)

      for secn in secns:
         section_citation = secn.text
      for sectxt in sectxts:
         section_txt = sectxt.text
         lst.append([
                    ch_citation,
                    subch_citation,
                    section_citation,
                    ch_title, 
                    subch_title,
                    section_txt
                    ])

print(lst)
```

**Outputs:**

```
Subchapter 1:
[['Ch 4:', 'subch. 1:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 1', 'belongs to left sec 1'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 1:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 1', 'belongs to left sec 2'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 1:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 1', 'belongs to left sec 3'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 1:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 1', 'belongs to left sec 4'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 1:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 1', 'belongs to left sec 5'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 1:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 1', 'belongs to left sec 6'], 

Subchapter 2:
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 2:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 2', 'belongs to left sec 1'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 2:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 2', 'belongs to left sec 2'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 2:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 2', 'belongs to left sec 3'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 2:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 2', 'belongs to left sec 4'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 2:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 2', 'belongs to left sec 5'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 2:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 2', 'belongs to left sec 6']]
```

**The Problem**

1. As you guys can tell the **subchapter_text** is being repeated on both subchapter 1 and subchapter 2.
2. Also it is only grabbing the last citation from **section_citation**
3. In some cases there wont be any subchapters only the chapter and section. Therefore ideally I would not want the section inside the subchapter for loop ... is there any list manipulation that can complete the **following output and make the following code work**

**Ideal Code for the future projects**

```
lst = []
s = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

chs = s.find_all('h1', attrs={'class':'ch'})
subchs = s.find_all('h2', attrs={'class': 'subchapter'})
secns = s.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'left'})
sectxts = s.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'right'})

if chs:
   for ch in chs:
      chapter = ch.text
      ch_citation = re.search(r".*:", chapter).group()
      ch_title = re.sub(r".*:","",chapter)

if subchs:
   for subch in subchs:
      subchapter = subch.text
      subch_citation = re.search(r".*:", subchapter).group()
      subch_title = re.sub(r".*:","",subchapter)
      
if secns and sectxts:
   for secn in secns:
      section_citation = secn.text
   for sectxt in sectxts:
      section_txt = sectxt.text
      
lst.append([ch_citation,subch_citation,section_citation,ch_title,subch_title,section_txt])
```

**!Ideal Output!**

```
Subchapter 1:
[['Ch 4:', 'subch. 1:', 'sec 1.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 1', 'belongs to left sec 1'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 1:', 'sec 2.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 1', 'belongs to left sec 2'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 1:', 'sec 3.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 1', 'belongs to left sec 3']

Subchapter 2: 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 2:', 'sec 4.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 2', 'belongs to left sec 4'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 2:', 'sec 5.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 2', 'belongs to left sec 5'], 
['Ch 4:', 'subch. 2:', 'sec 6.', 'Chapter Title', 'Subchapter Title 2', 'belongs to left sec 6']]
```

**Any advice, ideas, or help is greatly appreciated!**

Comment: if you want all citations then you should use `list` (`subch_citation = []`) to keep all of them and use `subch_citation.append()` to add to list. Normal assigning `subch_citation = ...` can keep only one value - and it keeps only last assigned value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what is needed, but you can use `.find_previous` to check in which chapter/subchpter etc. you're currently in. For example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """
... your html code from question ...
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

out = []
for c in soup.select(".left"):
    citation = c.text.strip()
    text = c.find_next(class_="right").text.strip()
    subchapter = c.find_previous(class_="subchapter").text.strip()
    chapter = c.find_previous(class_="ch").text.strip()

    out.append(
        [
            chapter.split(":")[0],
            subchapter.split(":")[0],
            citation,
            chapter.split(":")[1],
            subchapter.split(":")[1],
            text,
        ]
    )

df = pd.DataFrame(
    out,
    columns=[
        "chapter_no",
        "subchapter_no",
        "citation",
        "chapter_text",
        "subchapter_text",
        "text",
    ],
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  chapter_no subchapter_no citation   chapter_text     subchapter_text                   text
0       Ch 4      subch. 1   sec 1.  Chapter Title  Subchapter Title 1  belongs to left sec 1
1       Ch 4      subch. 1   sec 2.  Chapter Title  Subchapter Title 1  belongs to left sec 2
2       Ch 4      subch. 1   sec 3.  Chapter Title  Subchapter Title 1  belongs to left sec 3
3       Ch 4      subch. 2   sec 4.  Chapter Title  Subchapter Title 2  belongs to left sec 4
4       Ch 4      subch. 2   sec 5.  Chapter Title  Subchapter Title 2  belongs to left sec 5
5       Ch 4      subch. 2   sec 6.  Chapter Title  Subchapter Title 2  belongs to left sec 6
```